# Ways to transfer data at a time when the add-on get purchased

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

We are developing an Addon for the Dynamics CRM and we need pre-populated data in some of our master entities.
Are there any ways to import data at the same time when we deploy our Add-on in client CRM environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, via a tool called the [Dynamics 365 Package Deployer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn688182.aspx).

> Microsoft Dynamics CRM Package Deployer lets administrators deploy
>   packages on Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online) and Dynamics 365
>   (on-premises) instances. A “package” can consist of any or all of the
>   following:
>
> - One or more Dynamics 365 solution files.
> - Flat files or exported configuration data file from the Configuration
>     Migration tool. For more information about the tool, see [TechNet:
>     Manage your configuration data](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn647421.aspx).
> - Custom code that can run before, while, or after the package is deployed to the Dynamics 365 instance.
> - HTML content specific to the package that can display at the beginning and end of the deployment process. This can be useful to
>     provide a description of the solutions and files that are deployed in
>     the package.
>
> Microsoft Dynamics 365 provides you with a Visual Studio template for
>   creating these packages that can be used with the Package Deployer
>   tool to deploy them to a Dynamics 365instance.

[Here's](https://crmtipoftheday.com/587/tipster-guide-to-creating-dynamics-crm-package-deployer-package/) a video about creating a package.

And [another](https://crmtipoftheday.com/592/tipster-guide-to-deploying-dynamics-crm-package/) about deploying a package.

Comment: Hello Aron,
Thanks for your response.
Actually, I have installed one tool from the Microsoft App Store and I found that after installing a tool, some entities from these have data.
I need to do the same thing. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I'd have to analyze that particular tool, but my general guess would be that they're using Package Deployer.

Comment: Hello Aron, I have a doubt because, from my side, I didn't do anything to import the data. Maybe App Source is providing us feature to import the data automatically. I am not sure.

Comment: I am not an expert on Package Deployer, but what you're describing appears to be within its capabilities.

Comment: Aron, you are correct. we can use the same process as well to deploy the package from app source. The difference seems like the deployment process. Package process is the same which is described in your answer. I appriciate your support. Thanks a lot.

Comment: AppSource relies on Package Deployer to install content into the tenant. This can (and usually does) include data alongside customizations. Also, packages deployed via Package Deployer can (and often do) include code to manipulate the tenant and/or the data during the deployment process. A validation process to ensure the package adheres to policy must be undertaken when publishing content to AppSource.